# prestashop Invoice not displaying purchased product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have installed Prestashop 1.6.1.4.

After installation and enabling mail alert I have a problem and the problem is when a customer places an order the order details doesn't show in the order page!
After disabling this module the problem is still there!

what can I do to fix this problem?

**Added:**
I turned error on in config and i saw a lot of error that i think it doesn't relate to that module!

```
    [PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Unknown column 'original_wholesale_price' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `ps_order_detail` (`id_order`, `id_order_invoice`, `id_warehouse`, `id_shop`, `product_id`, `product_attribute_id`, `product_name`, `product_quantity`, `product_quantity_in_stock`, `product_quantity_return`, `product_quantity_refunded`, `product_quantity_reinjected`, `product_price`, `reduction_percent`, `reduction_amount`, `reduction_amount_tax_incl`, `reduction_amount_tax_excl`, `group_reduction`, `product_quantity_discount`, `product_ean13`, `product_upc`, `product_reference`, `product_supplier_reference`, `product_weight`, `tax_name`, `tax_rate`, `tax_computation_method`, `id_tax_rules_group`, `ecotax`, `ecotax_tax_rate`, `discount_quantity_applied`, `download_hash`, `download_nb`, `download_deadline`, `unit_price_tax_incl`, `unit_price_tax_excl`, `total_price_tax_incl`, `total_price_tax_excl`, `total_shipping_price_tax_excl`, `total_shipping_price_tax_incl`, `purchase_supplier_price`, `original_product_price`, `original_wholesale_price`) VALUES ('2', '0', '0', '1', '54', '140', 'سبد بافت استوانه زیباسازان - رنگ : قهوه ای', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '20000', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '20000', '20000', '20000', '20000', '0', '0', '0', '20000', '0')


at line 791 in file classes/db/Db.php

786.         if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
787.             $dbg = debug_backtrace();
788.             WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
789.         } elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
790.             if ($sql) {
791.                 throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
792.             }
793. 
794.             throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
795.         }
796.     }

DbCore->displayError - [line 425 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->query - [line 763 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->q - [line 514 - classes/db/Db.php] - [2 Arguments]
DbCore->insert - [line 487 - classes/ObjectModel.php] - [3 Arguments]
ObjectModelCore->add - [line 802 - classes/order/OrderDetail.php] - [2 Arguments]
OrderDetailCore->add - [line 445 - classes/ObjectModel.php] - [2 Arguments]
ObjectModelCore->save - [line 653 - classes/order/OrderDetail.php]
OrderDetailCore->create - [line 678 - classes/order/OrderDetail.php] - [7 Arguments]
OrderDetailCore->createList - [line 364 - classes/PaymentModule.php] - [7 Arguments]
PaymentModuleCore->validateOrder - [line 59 - modules/cashondelivery/controllers/front/validation.php] - [9 Arguments]
CashondeliveryValidationModuleFrontController->postProcess - [line 178 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
ControllerCore->run - [line 367 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 28 - index.php]
```

any idea with this errors?

[screenshot of the red frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKphM.jpg)

Comment: Which mail alert module are you using?

Comment: "Email Alerts v3.6.0"

Comment: I think this problem is not related with "Email Alerts" module. You should check the `override/classes/order` folder - maybe other modules added some code there.

Comment: in this folder exist just one php file (index.php) and the code of this file is:`header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
    
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
    
header("Location: ../");
exit;`

Comment: This `index.php` is standard. So this is not a source of your issue. There can be many reasons... Try to disable all overrides (in `Performance` tab), enable debuggin (basic coding is needed), uninstall unused modules, change language - you need to find the cause of the issue first.

Comment: I turned error on in config and i saw a lot of error that i think it doesn't relate to that module!

Comment: Yes, as I've said this problem is not related with "Email Alerts" module at all.

Comment: I added some explain (top)

Comment: It says you don't have a column `original_wholesale_price` in the table `ps_order_detail` of your database. But it is a standard one column. Maybe you have modified something manually.

Comment: Use `phpMyAdmin` and add it there again.

Comment: Thanks, but add it where? in ps_order_detail ?

Comment: Yes, add a column `original_wholesale_price` to the table `ps_order_detail` - if it is not there already.

Comment: I added but there is another error: `Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'` what is this one?

Comment: I can't say not seeing your MySQL query.

Comment: The first problem has been solved! and the products shown in order page! but the new problem is still there, when (COD module) ask you confirm your order, there are some error! `[PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Duplicate entry '2-2' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: It means you have old data in your database tables and trying to add another '2', '2' on top.

Comment: how can i fix this one?

Comment: It solved! Thank you so much Indre